# Does there exists group isomorphism $ϕ: \Bbb Z_{40} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_{40}$ such that $ϕ(17) = 15$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Does there exists group isomorphism $ϕ: \Bbb Z_{40} \rightarrow \Bbb Z_{40}$
> such that $ϕ(17) = 15$?

What I tried so far:
$ϕ(17) = 17*ϕ(1) = 15$.

And now I wanted to show the equation $17x = 15 \pmod {40}$ have no solution, But this didn't got me anywhere.

Any hints will be usefull :)

Comment: Hint: look at the orders of $15$ and $17$ in $\Bbb Z_{40}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\gcd(17,40)=1$. So $\overline{17}$ generates the group $\mathbb{Z}_{40}$.

The isomorphic image of this generator $\overline{17}$ must also be a generator. However $15$ does not generate the group.

$17x=15$ will have a solution because $17$ is a generator of the group.

In general if you have a cyclic group $G=\langle a\rangle$. Then $f:G\to G$ is an isomorphism(called Automorphism) iff $G=\langle f(a)\rangle$.